# Is the extension $\mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} \right)$ simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Context: The book *Galois Theory* by Ian Stewart, 4th edition, Chapter 5, Exercise 5.7.

Is the field extension $\mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} \right)$ of the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers a simple extension?

That is, is there an real number $\alpha$ such that 
$$ \mathbb{Q} ( \alpha ) = \mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} \right)? $$

Of course, we can show that 
$$  \mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \right) \subset \mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} \right) . $$
Am I right?

Can we also show that 
$$  \mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2},  \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} \right) \subset \mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \right)? $$

Or, is there a way of conclusively proving that showing this is not possible?

Is there a way of showing using some other technique that this extension is or is not simple?

Comment: The [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) gives you the existence. Its constructive proof gives you a way to test that particular generator.

Comment: Note that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ has degree 8, which is the degree of the extension field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: @rogerl can you please explicitly show in a full-fledged answer that the following holds? $$\mathbb{Q}\left( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} \right) \subset \mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \right). $$

Comment: @egorovik can you please explicitly show that the following holds? $$\mathbb{Q}\left( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} \right) \subset \mathbb{Q} \left( \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \right). $$ Please post your work as an answer.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Do you have problems figuring out the answer from either my hint or egorovik's? If so, it would be helpful if you told us what confuses you.

Comment: @rogerl actually, Ian Stewart hasn't discussed either the Primitive Element Theorem or any result involving the degree of the minimal polynomial. So I would appreciate if either you or egorovik give an explicit formulation of the required inclusion relation.